# SD over SPI returns invalid response on CMD8

Tags: embedded, driver, sd-card, lpc

I'm working on an SPI SD driver for an LPC4088 microcontroller. However, when I send `CMD8` (after `CMD0`) to detect if I'm working with a V2 or high capacity card, I get a weird response. Instead of getting a correct response( `0x01` for highest bits, `0x1AA` for the lower 12) or an error I get `0x00 00 00 02 1F`, which doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Code I use for initialization:

```
bool initialize () {
    //0. Initialize SPI
    SPI::init();

    //1. Set clock to 400kHz
    SPI::set_clock(400000);


    //2. Assert CS signal (=0)
    assert_cs();

    // 3. Delay at least 74 clocks
    delay8(10);
    // 4. Deassert CS signal
    deassert_cs();

    // 5. Delay at least 16 clocks
    delay8(2);

    uint8_t argument[4];
    reset_argument(argument);

    // 6. Send CMD0 (reset, go to idle)
    if (!send_command(CMD::GO_IDLE_STATE, CMD_RESPONSE_SIZE::GO_IDLE_STATE, response, argument)) {
        return false;
    }

    // 7. Send CMD8
    bool version2;
    reset_argument(argument);
    pack_argument(argument, 0x1AA);

    if (!send_command(CMD::SEND_IF_COND, CMD_RESPONSE_SIZE::SEND_IF_COND, response, argument)) { 
        return false; 
    }
    if ((response[0] & 0xFE) == 0x04) {
        //unknown command. This means we have version1
        version2 = false;
    } else if (response[0] & 0xFE) {
        //other error, let's bail
         return false;
    } else {
        //Response, we're version2
        version2 = true;
        if (response[4] != 0xAA) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //....
}
```

send_command code:

```
    bool send_command(CMD::value cmd, uint8_t response_size, uint8_t *response, uint8_t *argument) {

        assert_cs();
        Crc7_SD crc;
        crc += cmd | 0x40;
        crc += argument[3] & 0xFF;
        crc += argument[2] & 0xFF;
        crc += argument[1] & 0xFF;
        crc += argument[0] & 0xFF;

        SPI::send(cmd | 0x40);
        SPI::send(argument[3] & 0xFF);
        SPI::send(argument[2] & 0xFF);
        SPI::send(argument[1] & 0xFF);
        SPI::send(argument[0] & 0xFF);
        SPI::send((crc << 1) | 1);

        volatile uint8_t data;
        {
            unsigned int timeout = SD_CMD_TIMEOUT;
            do {
                data = SPI::receive();
                --timeout;
            } while(timeout && (data & 0x80));
            if (timeout == 0) {
                deassert_cs();
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < response_size; i++) {
            //First byte is already read above
            if (response) {
                response[i] = data;
            }
            data = SPI::receive();

        }

        deassert_cs();

        return true;
    }
```

To make sure that I didn't had an error in the SPI protocol I've verified the input and output with a logic analyzer. Result: [CMD0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdsMp.png) followed by [CMD8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ggNH.png). It seems that I'm sending the correct commands, but still I get this weird response.

Additional info about the setup:

- Microcontroller is an LPC4088
- Microcontroller is connected with [this OEM board](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/oem/lpc4088_oem.php)
- The SD card module is connected to the serial expansion connector of the OEM board
- The logic analyzer is connected to the SD card module
- I've used 2 different versions of both the microcontroller and the OEM board to rule out that there is a hardware error in one of those. Unfortunately I don't have a second SD controller available.
- I've used a SanDisk Ultra SDHC 4GB Class 6 SD card and a Transcend SDHC 4GB Class 4 SD card, both gave exactly the same result.

And last but not least, I have very little experience with embedded software, so it might just be some small stupid error.

Comment: The order of your arguments seems to be odd for me. You send first `argument[3]`, I would assume at first `argument[0]`. But this depends of your `pack_argument()` function

Comment: And `crc` isn't initialized before you use it in `crc+=cmd | 0x40`. The sending crc-character for CMD0 should be 0x95, and for CMD8 it should be 0x87 (read from my working source)

Comment: @jeb - The arguments are send in the correct order, as you can see in the output of the logic analyser. Also, the crc is initialized correctly. `0x95` and `0x87` are send with their corresponding commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that there was some noise on the MISO line. The code was correct, but due to the noise the microcontroller got a different result then intended. With the help of some electronics guy I was able to filter this by soldering a capacitor between MISO and ground.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but loading data lines with caps seems a little unusual.  You may have some serious layout issues - if the wires are long, possibly you need terminating resistors.  You may also want to check if your power supply is adequately bypassed.

Comment: This is currently only for a development setup. Our custom pcbs aren't finished yet, but I do need to develop the software for it already (I only do the software). So this is just a dirty patch for my development setup, the real setup will of course be designed better (by someone who knows a lot more about pcb design than I do).

Comment: Do you have pull-up on the data lines and a pulldown on the clock line ? -If not, try and see if it can replace the capacitor (because the capacitor sounds wrong to me).

Comment: One more detail: Perhaps you would want to also check response[3] == 1 and response[1..2] == 0, just to make sure you don't get debris back. As far as I've read, you should verify the entire response.